# Separate formula

Tags: r

I keep getting this error, when i try separate my column by ".". My code is

```
txt <- "'Rural Male' 'Rural Female' 'Urban Male' 'Urban Female'
50-54 11.7 8.7 15.4 8.4
55-59 18.1 11.7 24.3 13.6
60-64 26.9 20.3 37.0 19.3
65-69 41.0 30.9 54.6 35.1
70-74 66.0 54.3 71.1 50.0)"

data <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = txt)

datanew <- data %>% tbl_df() %>% mutate(age= row.names(data)) %>% gather(key, death_rate, -age)`

separate(data = datanew,col = key, sep = ".", into = c("a","b"))
```

Warning message
Expected 2 pieces. Additional pieces discarded in 20 rows [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20].

Comment: Use `sep` uses regular expressions, and in regular expressions `.` means "any character". You need to escape it with backslashes to get a literal `.`, use `sep = "\\."`

Answer (score 0):

Use `sep` uses regular expressions, and in regular expressions `.` means "any character". You need to escape it with backslashes to get a literal `.`, use `sep = "\\."`

```
separate(data = datanew, col = key, sep = "\\.", into = c("a","b"))
# # A tibble: 20 x 4
#    age   a     b      death_rate
#    <chr> <chr> <chr>  <chr>     
#  1 50-54 Rural Male   11.7      
#  2 55-59 Rural Male   18.1      
#  3 60-64 Rural Male   26.9      
#  4 65-69 Rural Male   41        
#  5 70-74 Rural Male   66    
#  ...
```

The default for `separate` is any non-letter non-number. So in this case you could also just use the default:

```
separate(data = datanew, col = key, into = c("a","b"))
# same result
```